# Can't commit - '.git/index.lock': File exists. Even though, there is no file like that

Tags: bash, git

Getting an error when trying to commit and push:

`Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to continue.`

What I tried:

1. finding that file and deleting it - there is no file index.lock in this repo. It is not there, neither in the .git folder nor in git/refs/head/my_branch (yes, hidden files are shown, yes I tried through sudo).
2. completely delete the repo and clone it once again, and then committing.
3. kill all of the git processes.
4. hard reset of computer.
5. rm .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG - no such file

No result.

Comment: `sudo` does not bring any value to your research.

Comment: just trying @axiac all of possible options

Comment: How could `rm .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` help when the error says to remove `.git/index.lock`?

Comment: just trying @axiac all of possible options –

Comment: So `ls -l .git/index.lock` doesn't show a file? And neither does `ls -l "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/index.lock"`?

Comment: @knittl, that's right - no such file or directory.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory/repository (and on the correct host)? Do you have submodules or nested git repositories inside your working tree?

Comment: right directory and right repo. I don't have nested repos

Comment: any repo, or just this one?

Comment: Does `touch .git/index.lock` create it?

Comment: If you make a new copy of the repo directory (e.g. `cp -a $HOME/src/myrepo $HOME/src/myrepo.copy`), does the problem still remain in the copy?

Comment: thanks, everyone for joining to help! I just made a regular typo.

Answer (score 1):

the error has nothing to do with the real cause of the problem. Spend time "fighting" with what I am not suppose to "fight" at all, lol.

I did `ga . & gcmsg "updated" && gp` instead of `ga . && gcmsg "updated" && gp`

Maybe will be helpful for someone.

Comment: And that's why being explicit about what commands you enter when the problem occurs is useful. If you had done that, you would have probably found the problem even before posting the question (or someone else would have quickly pointed it out).

Comment: yes, that's absolutely right @JoachimSauer

Comment: This question should be deleted: it's not reproducible, it was caused by a typo, and it does not help future visitors